# Apple ID with iCloud email address?

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id

Can you create an Apple ID with the iCloud email address it comes with? (if I enable it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a catch 22 situation. You want to create an Apple ID with an iCloud email address which is created when you create an Apple ID with an iCloud email address which is created…

If you mean a new Apple ID with an old iCloud email, then no, that’s not possible.